# Repeat json field with different name

Tags: java, json, jackson

i have a POJO mapped which i serialize using `Jackson`

```
public class Foo{

private String bar;

// public setter and getter for bar
}
```

it serializes to

> {bar:"value"}

is there a jackson annotation to get **another field in the JSON** with the *same value* but with a different alias name, something like

> {bar:"value", another_bar:"value"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for duplicating the value, though why you'd want to waste space like that is puzzling:

```
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    @JsonProperty
    public String getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }
    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @JsonProperty("another_bar")
    public String getAnotherBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }
}
```